# Concatenating zeros with a string

Tags: java, string

I am trying to append zeros to the string to make it a 32 bit number. but the output does not show the appended zeros. why is it so?

```
    System.out.print("\nEnter the linear Address (32bit) :\t");
    String linear_hex= sc.nextLine();
    String linear_bin= Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(linear_hex,16));

    if(linear_bin.length() != 32)
    {

        for(int i= linear_bin.length(); i<=32; i++)
            linear_bin= 0+linear_bin;
    }
```

Output:

```
Enter the linear Address (32bit) :  12345678
Linear Address = 10010001101000101011001111000
```

I also tried `linear_bin= "0"+linear_bin;` and `"0".concat(linear_bin);` but the output is still the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code works fine for me:

```
System.out.print("\nEnter the linear Address (32bit) :\t");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String linear_hex= sc.nextLine();
    String linear_bin= Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(linear_hex,16));

    if(linear_bin.length() != 32) {         
        // Should be i < 32 instead of i <= 32, else you end up with an extra 0
        // Also consider using StringBuilder instead of String concatenation here
        for(int i= linear_bin.length(); i < 32; i++)
            linear_bin= 0+linear_bin;
    }
    System.out.println(linear_bin);
```

Input:

```
123456
```

Output:

```
00000000000100100011010001010110
```

However, you can achieve this more easily using `String.format()` method. Remove the `if` block, and add this print statement:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%32s", linear_bin).replace(' ', '0'));
```